# Powershell script to get value based on todays date comparison

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

This is my first time automating excel report with Powershell, thus my PS skill is very minimal.

My task is that I will be receiving a report that contains the column "Iteration path" & some other columns. This iteration path value should be extracted from another excel file like a mapping table lets say.

The mapping table has a column "start date" & "end date" & a corresponding "Iteration path" value. I would like to compare todays date, if it falls between these start n end date, assign the corresponding "iteration path" value to the excel report, whilst maintaining the other columns.

The report is an csv file & the mapping table is an xlsx file.

Please assist me, thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be done through a if loop.

```
$contentfromcsv = Import-csv CSVFIleName.csv
$count = $contentfromcsv.count
$currentdate = get-date
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $count; $i++)
{
If ($contentfromcsv[$i].Startdate -lt $currentdate) -and ($contentfromcsv[$i].enddate -lt $currentdate))
   {
   #Do the next steps only if the current date is falling between start 
   date and enddate
   }
}
```

Comment: noted, my other concern would be as to how to perform the loop in the other excel file, while getting the corresponding value to be updated to similar column name in other excel file? whereas the whole column has the same value that matched

Comment: PowerShell don't have the capability to read content from excel. Either you need to depend on some third-party module or use a csv instead of excel. I dont know the entire context of your requirement but on a high level, I would be using the below steps.

Comment: I have updated the initial comment with a high level view. Please have  a look.

Comment: Thank you, your answer has helped. My solution able to extract the adjacent value, just need to assign it to the final report. This is what i came up with;

Comment: $reference = "C:\Script\Mapping2.csv" 
$output = "C:\Script\Filter\SV4.csv"
$ref = Import-Csv -Delimiter ',' -Path $reference

$dateFormat = "d/M/yyyy"
$current = Get-Date

$filter = @()
foreach ($Row in $ref) {
    $StartDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Row.'Start Date', $dateFormat, $null)
    $EndDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Row.'End Date', $dateFormat, $null)
    if (($StartDate -le $current) -and ($EndDate -ge $current))
    { 
        $filter += $Row 
    }
}
$filter | Export-Csv -Path $output -NoTypeInformation